Projection of a point on a NURBS curve or surface: existency
Could I say that for a point to have an (inner) projection onto a NURBS curve (surface), it must have an inner projection to an edge (surface) of the NURBS control polygon?
Let say the curve (surface) has the parameter domain $0 \leq \xi \leq 1$, the inner projection $\xi_0$ means $\xi_0 \in (0,1)$.

Can you define precisely (in mathematical terms) what an "inner projection" means?

@WolfgangBangerth It means that it is not on the boundary of the curve or surface.

I don't think you can say so, no. You can look at pictures of control polygons and the corresponding surfaces (see for example https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Uniform_Rational_B-Spline#/media/Datei:NURBS_3-D_surface.gif) and note that the control polygon extends beyond the surface. So a projection being in its interior does not guarantee that this is a projection on the surface's interior.
